# ai contact safe captcha not working in joomla 2.5

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, joomla2.5, captcha

I installed a contact us component named ai_contact_safe in my joomla 2.5 site.the issue is, I can't find captcha in this component.I can only find 3 dots in that place.I enabled the captcha option in the admin side.

here is my [link](http://keralacarpentry.com/freedom2/index.php/contact-us)

Comment: Is this reCapcha? Is so don't you have to configure the license?

Comment: I enabled the captcha plugin in the admin side.

Comment: did you registered and got your token at the reCaptcha site?

Comment: @Unykvis configure licence means what?

Comment: @Preethy https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create

Comment: I have installed it in a Demo site and I have the same problem. Contact the owner. There is no configuration in that component.

Comment: @danishhashmi i put the token in to my site but not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a Jquery no conflict bug and it is easily fix. Open you template and add:

```
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

It will solve.

Comment: i put this to my template file but there is no change happend

Comment: You need to put it after mootools and jQuery are loaded. Please confirm.

Comment: Put it here: BEFORE </head> Try it.